# Node.js: Sharp package unable to install

Tags: node.js, image, buffer, sharp

I'm trying to install the Sharp package to compress buffers for images. Now when I install the package via `npm install sharp --save`, and try to use this line of code:

```js
const sharp = require('sharp');
```

I get the following error: https://textuploader.com/1gvep .
This is the mentioned log: https://textuploader.com/1gvez .
I did some research before posting this. This is what I've tried:

- use --ignore-scripts=false flag
- use --unsafe-perm flag
- remove sharp package from node_modules and run `npm install --ignore-scripts=false` again
- run `npm rebuild`

But nothing of this would help so far. Now some people seemed to solve the problem by downgrading to Node 10, but this is not an option for me because I need to use it together with Discord.js which requires at least Node 12. The idea I'd have in mind is writing the image to a tmp folder, compressing the written image with another libarary and reload it, but that's not very elegant in my opinion. Now my questions are:

- What else can I try to install Sharp correctly?
- Are there alternatives to shrink image buffer sizes down?

**Edit**:
As suggested by Alex, I tried out Jimp and simply reduced the image size for the beginning. I'll share my code here in case somebody looks for an alternative.

```js
let buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png'); //from node-canvas
Jimp.read(buffer)
.then(image => {
   image.resize(width>>1, height>>1).getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_PNG)
   .then(comprBuffer => {
      /* use the new buffer */
   });
})
.catch(err => { 
   console.log(err) 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing sharp and had no issues on the following versions:

Node v12.16.1
Npm v6.13.4

How about using Jimp instead?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp

Comment: I tried out Jimp and it does exactly what I want to do. Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)